# Why was my question put on hold as “too broad”?

Tags: discussion

I have a question regarding this post: [How to catch all exceptions in Web API 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25395407/how-to-catch-all-exceptions-in-web-api-2/)

For some reason the post was flagged as being "too broad", despite the fact that an accurate answer was able to be provided and accepted within minutes. The question is very specifically about creating a RESTful API using a framework called Web API 2, and there is really only one way to do what I was asking - that approach was in the answer that Ofer Zelig generously offered.

The question was favourited three times so obviously others found it simple and concise, and the answer was upvoted three times as well. This clearly demonstrates that people searched for the question and got the exact answer they wanted - isn't this what Stack Overflow is for?

I'm willing to take suggestions of course. How could I have improved my question to make it "less broad"?  Or was this just an honest mistake by the moderator maybe?

Edit: The question has now been re-opened, but my question still stands: why was it closed in the first place?

Comment: In case it's relevant, there was a user who posted several comments under the question criticising what I was trying to do. It was later revealed that having not read the question correctly he didn't realise I was specifically talking about RESTful APIs in Web API 2.  I'm assuming it was him that flagged it, and given he had very high rep is it possible the moderator simply trusted his judgement and put it on hold without checking for himself?

Comment: "Favourite" ≠ "simple and concise" by definition. I sometimes bookmark *bad* questions to check upon them later.

Comment: @Jongware no problem, I understand that, but combining that information with the other things I mentioned gives the impression that the question was fine. (Which I would argue is most certainly the case since it is now re-opened).

Comment: They probably got hung up on *"I'm not sure how to handle errors effectively"*. That question would be too broad. You do narrow the scope significantly as the post goes on, but not everyone gets that far.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wouldn't worry about it. Honestly, particularly since it's been reopened, I think those original voters just misunderstood your question. I don't think it ever deserved to be closed. They probably saw a pending close vote, read the title, and assumed you were looking for some cure-all solution to fixing bugs in a program.

That said, I think you could, perhaps, improve your title. I must reiterate, I think it's more than fine as your question stands--in fact I favourited it, and I don't do that much at all--but if your title was a bit more specific, you probably could have avoided all those problems in the first place.  Perhaps even a minor change, like "How can I catch all otherwise uncaught exceptions in Web API?" (although, of course, we aren't really supposed to include tags in titles, but you see the kind of change I mean) Just something to hint that you're talking specifically about exceptions that were completely unexpected.

But yeah, no, I think that question was fine. It looks broad, but anyone who spends any time to actually read it should be more than capable of understanding what you were going for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I did wonder if the title itself was part of the issue.  I'll take that advice on board for future questions.

Comment: Matthew Haugen, defending and teaching newbs since forever!

Comment: Including a tag in the title if it makes sense (ie: it fits in the flow of the sentence), then there is no problem. The problem is with adding tags purely as tags.